# Using Bass.Net to stream audio from RTSP on C#

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, rtsp, bass.dll

I have a video server streaming MPEG-4(video/audio)

I need to get the audio from the MPEG-4...is it possible to get only the audio???

I would like to have some tutorials, samples, examples or something useful to start
programming my application.

I found this : [Bass.Net](http://www.un4seen.com/) to stream audio, but I don't know if it supports RTSP, and I would like to know if someone has any tutorial or something useful.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer... I was banned during the summer ;P

Answer (score 0):

You can get the individual packets using my library and do something with them.

You can also aggregate the source using my library.

The library is @ http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

There is an article @ CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp which explains how it works.

If you need anything else let me know!